# Accessing entries in a csv files for computation F#

Tags: arrays, math, csv, f#

How can I access the entries in a csv file in order to perform calculations on them in F#?

I can read the csv file into memory in the usual way, but once there I am stuck.

Ideally I would just create arrays from the columns and then use array.map2 to perform calculations.

So I array 1 is some website usage metric, and column 2 is the number of users that reached the value in column 1 (say made 6 visits to a website) we could calculate the mean number of visits by multiplying each entry in an array of column 1, by an array made from column 2 and dividing by the array.sum of column 2.

I have tried the csv to Array code on F# snippets, http://fssnip.net/3T, but it produces and array for me that is a series of string tuples.

Can anyone suggest a better approach?

EDIT: Some sample input would be similar to this:-

```
     Visits Count
     1  8
     2  9
     3  5
     4  3
     5  2
     6  1
     7  1
    10  1
```

And the output would be to return the mean of the data, in this case 2.87 (to 2 decimal places).

EDIT 2: The current output from the CSV to array code I found is this

```
     val it : seq<BookWindow> =
            seq [{Visits = 1;
                  Count = 8;}; {Visits = 2;
                           Count = 9;}; {Visits = 3;
                                  Count = 5;}; {Visits = 4;
                                              Count = 3;}; ...]
```

which is not so useful for calculations...

Comment: Can you add a sample input and output? For a specific purpose, you don't need to use complex techniques as the snippet you mentioned.

Comment: Yes I think I am overcomplicating things! :)

Comment: Just some OCD kicking in CSVs have commas in - hence the name. TSV have tabs :-)

Comment: Yes, the file in question is a csv file, I coped and pasted from excel so there are no commas in what I wrote. Sorry for any confusion!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What I do is create a record type so I can use strongly typed operations lateron, and then read the textfile into a `seq<myRecord>` very quickly like this code below. If i intend to reuse this lateron I usually move the method to the record as `static member fromFile`. The seq is very useful if you work with large textfiles as I do usually, it uses very little memory this way.

*edit* this is cleaner:

```
open System.IO

type myRecord = { 
    Visits: int
    Count: int 
} with
    static member fromFile file = 
        file
        |> File.ReadLines       // expose as seq<string>
        |> Seq.skip 1           // skip headers
        |> Seq.map (fun s-> s.Split '\t') // split each line into array
        |> Seq.map (fun a -> {Visits=int a.[0]; Count=int a.[1]}) // and create record

myRecord.fromFile @"D:\data.csv"
|> Seq.fold (fun (tv, tc) r -> (tv+r.Visits*r.Count, tc+r.Count))(0,0)
|> (fun t -> float (fst t) / float (snd t))
//val mean : float = 2.866666667
```

Comment: No worries! Getting the mean out once I can access the entries is no problem at all :)

Answer (score 6):

It is worth adding that with F# 3.0 type providers, accessing CSV files is getting a lot simpler. A type provider can take a look at the CSV data statically during compilation and generate the type to represent columns (like `BookWindow`) and then it infers data types of individual columns.

For example, take a look at the *"Using the Yahoo Finance Type Provider"* article under *"Financial Modeling"* on the [new version of Try F# web site](http://www.tryfsharp.org/Learn/financial-computing#using-yahoo). You can write something like:

```
#r "Samples.Csv.dll"

// Type provider that generates schema based on CSV file located online
[<Literal>]
let url = "http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=MSFT"
let msft = new Samples.FSharp.CsvProvider.MiniCsv<url>()

// The provider automatically infers the structure and we
// can access columns as properties of the 'row' object
for row in msft.Data do
  printfn "%A %f" row.Date row.Close
```

As far as I know, the most recent publicly available version of the CSV provider is in the [F# 3.0 Sample Pack](http://fsharp3sample.codeplex.com/). I have a possibly better version that also handles type inference on [my GitHub repo](https://github.com/tpetricek/Documents/tree/master/Samples).

Once you have the data in memory, you can do calculations using standard F# functions. For example, to calculate the average closing stock price (you can try that on Try F#), you can write:

```
 Seq.average [ for row in msft.Data -> row.Close ]
```

This generates a list with just closing prices and then calls standard average function on the numbers.

Comment: F# 3.0 is in VS 2012 isn't it? Must have a word with work about an upgrade if so.....

Comment: @SimonHayward Yes, F# 3.0 is available only in VS 2012. Although, you can also get it in the Express edition for free: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fsharpteam/archive/2012/09/12/announcing-the-release-of-f-tools-for-visual-studio-express-2012-for-web.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You probably are overcomplicating things and this is not the cleanest solution, but you can still work with what you have. Map that BookWindow type into separate arrays if that provides a good way to do your calculations.

```
 type BookWindow = { Visits: int
                     Count: int }
 // Sample data
 let list = [|{Visits = 1; Count = 8;}; {Visits = 2; Count = 9;}; {Visits = 3; Count = 5;}|]

 let visitcol = list |> Array.map (fun r -> r.Visits)
 let countcol = list |> Array.map (fun r -> r.Count)
 Array.map2( fun v c -> v * c) visitcol countcol
```

Comment: Ok, thank you. Do you know a simpler solution somewhere for reading in and accessing csv entries in F#? Probably just a basic tutorial would do, I'm floundering a bit.